# forfile and AD homefolders doesnt work

Tags: batch-file

we have an active directory with about 80 users.

what i want to do now is place in each userfolder a script that the user can run for themselves and it makes a log file in that same folder with files older than 5 days.

The homefolder for each user is mapped as drive in windows to the letter h
right now i have this:

```
forfiles -p "%cd%" -s -m *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c echo @path >> %cd%\log.txt"
```

but it throws me this error.

```
H:\>forfiles -p "H:\" -s -m *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c echo @path >> H:\\log.txt"
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@path'.
```

is there any way to solve this?

if i run in on my local pc with a test folder it works fine.

Comment: Did you read the `ForFiles` usage information, _output when entering `ForFiles /?` at the Command Prompt_? Also did you try moving the closing doublequote?

Comment: Yes tried both of thosr things. On the pc itself not using the h drive wich is the home folder does work

Comment: Try using `-p "H:\\"`; I believe `forfiles` is escaping the closing `"` when just specifying `-p "H:\"`...

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the closing doublequote, if you move it to before your redirection it certainly would make more sense, *as would changing it to **`>`** instead of **`>>`**.*

The fix to your issue, is when you use the `/P` option, you cannot doublequote it, and also include a trailing backslash, *(it's one or the other)*.

**My reading is that the backslash is escaping the doublequote.**

Because drives tend to require a trailing backslash, all you have to do is remove the doublequotes around it, *(they're not needed anyhow because drives don't include spaces)*.

Also please remember that, as already inferred in my comment, `ForFiles` already uses the current directory by default so removing it entirely is easier.

Comment: got it working now with this line:
forfiles -p H:\ -s -m *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c echo @path > log.txt

but it doenst look in subdirecotys but the -s is for that right? how can i fix that is does that but it create the log file in the subdirectoy and not in the main directory and i want all the files that need to be deleted in the main directoy logfile

Comment: @Klaas, you need to close the doublequote after `@path`; _I told you to move it, not remove it_!